# SQL Server CE select row values with max date

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL Server CE that does not support sub-queries. And I have a table, that contains the result (value) of the check by dates. I need to select ID's with the last date, that was checked.

I have these columns:

```
ID 
ID_Tags    + 
ID_Url     + 
ID_Page    + 
DateDownloaded 
Value
```

The 3 columns marked with "+" together represent one checked instance, for which the value is needed.

So I would like to select ID where ID_Tags, ID_Url and ID_Page are representing an unique combination and DateDownloaded is the last for this combination.

Comment: So, do you need the id for a specific combination of things (ie. "where id_tags = XXX and id_url = YYY and id_page = ZZZ") or do you need a table with all the ids for each combination?

Comment: The first thing. Unique ID's for a specific combination. There can be many equal combinations, but I need only ID's with the last "DateDownloaded" field for each combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Though, SQL Server CE does not support sub-query, it supports "IN" condition. So, I have written this query in the next way that works:

```
 SELECT ID, ID_Tags, ID_Url, ID_Page, MAX(DateDownloaded) as DateDownloaded
    FROM RealRecords
    WHERE DateDownloaded IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(DateDownloaded)
        FROM RealRecords
        GROUP BY ID_Tags, ID_Url, ID_Page
    )
AND ID IN
(
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM RealRecords
    GROUP BY ID_SetTags, ID_Url_Adresses, ID_SeoPage
)
    GROUP BY ID, ID_Tags, ID_Url, ID_Page
```

This query contains everythig is needed and can be modified to return only ID.

ID IN was added in case some DateDownloaded would be equal. ID is a primary key with auto-increment, so the last value will be 100% the last one, combining this check with the DateDownloaded column.